# Access timezone informations of datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I can create a timezone specific `datetime` object like this

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone()
```

Result is

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 2, 15, 12, 2, 807451, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200), 'CEST'))
```

It looks like that `tzinfo` is represented by two values/attributes: A timedelta and a string. But how can I access them?
I would like to do something like this

```
d.tzinfo.delta
d.tzinfo.name
```

I need this informations to be able to (de)serialize the datetime to and from JSON.

I don't want to use third-party packages for such solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tzinfo` in this case is an instance of the [`datetime.timezone()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects):

> The `timezone` class is a subclass of `tzinfo`, each instance of which represents a timezone defined by a fixed offset from UTC.

You can use the [`tzinfo.utcoffset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.utcoffset) and `tzinfo.utcname()` methods to access the delta and name. For `timezone()` instances the argument each of these take is ignored, but normally you'd pass in the `datetime` instance they are attached to:

```
d.tzinfo.utcoffset(d)
d.tzinfo.utcname(d)
```

You'd usually call these *on the `datetime.datetime` instance*, which has the same methods (but which take no arguments) and these will then handle passing in the right argument to the methods on the contained `tzinfo` attribute.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone()
>>> d.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)
>>> d.tzname()
'CEST'
>>> d.tzinfo.utcoffset(d)
datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)
>>> d.tzinfo.utcoffset(d) is d.utcoffset()  # they are the same object
True
```

The `datetime.timezone()` subclass is just one implementation of a `tzinfo` time zone, 3rd-party libraries like pytz offer their own, and the `utcoffset()` and `tzname()` return values may well vary for timezones with historical information attached.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about datetime.tzinfo, which is an abstract base class, as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo).

datetime comes with an implementation of the tzinfo abstract base class called datetime.timezone, which is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone).

Just below that last link are the docs on timezone.utcoffset and timezone.utcname, which are ways to access the properties you asked about on the tzinfo if it is a timezone. However, this is not the only implementation of that abstract class. If you are using the pytz timezone, for example, then you'll need to read the docs on that instead.

Comment: Since you said you're not using third-party packages, I assume you are just using the datetime.timezone, in which case the caveat I gave at the end doesn't apply to you. It may become relevant if you change your mind and start using a third-party package later, though.